# Python Tkinter pause screen redraw

Tags: python, tkinter, redraw

I have seen a couple of questions asking how to force a screen redraw in tkinter (which can be done using `update_idletasks`. I would like to do the opposite: suspend Tkinter's automatic screen redrawing until I have completed some major surgery to the application window - insert, delete, reposition a large number of widgets on a canvas, and then activate automatic screen redrawing after I'm done. Is that possible? I can't find any documented way of doing this. I'm using Tkinter with Python 3.

Comment: That's the way it works by default.  If the mainloop isn't running, and you're not calling `.update()` or `.update_idletasks()`, none of your canvas changes get drawn.

Comment: @jasonharper - but the mainloop *is* running. Is there a way to suspend it?

Comment: How are you managing to let the mainloop have any CPU time while you're doing your canvas updates?  You'd have to go out of your way to allow that.

Comment: @jasonharper - isn't the mainloop running in a separate thread? I was under the impression that it is.

Comment: With your ```mainloop```-issue: You can break the ```mainloop```by instantiating ```.quit()```. After that you can just simply start the ```mainloop```again if you want. But keep in mind that the window will be closed if you run it over the console and you don't give the program any tasks after ```.quit()```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to do the opposite: suspend Tkinter's automatic screen redrawing until I have completed some major surgery to the application window - insert, delete, reposition a large number of widgets on a canvas, and then activate automatic screen redrawing after I'm done. Is that possible?

Yes, it's possible. That's precisely how tkinter works by default.

Tkinter runs in a single thread. While any of your code is running, tkinter has no ability to update the screen unless you explicitly call `update` or `update_idletasks` for it to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.